# What causes non-perfect circles in subdivision?

Tags: subdivision-surface, topology

I've noticed sometimes that when subd modeling, and using "Loop Tools > Circle," I still end up with a circle that isn't perfectly round. A good example is this first example on the left. I would have expected the resulting circle to be perfectly round, yet it's not. The second two examples on the right seem more or less perfectly circular. Why is this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not enough geometry for the subdivision to follow a circular shape, the first one is basically a "Rounded" rectangle rather than a circle.

Comment: Is it generally agreed upon in subd modeling that you need to inset more than a single face to create a round circle?

Comment: It all depends on your final goal; but the less geometry, the less is going to have the subdivision to work with